# Why does my iPad media query clash with my desktop media query?

Tags: html, css, ipad

This is how i code my desktop CSS like this.

```
@media (max-width: 1367px)
```

This is my iPad CSS

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) 
and (min-resolution: 132dpi)
```

Unfortunately, the CSS codes that i used to code the desktop CSS clashes and overwrite the CSS of the iPad. Why is this so? Each target different devices but why do they clash with each other despite iPad's media query being more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 media queries are not mutually exclusive, and as such are *both* processed in order when both apply - media queries have no specificity, just applicability. It then becomes a matter of specificity at the CSS level: more specific rules in CSS get precedence, and in case of identical specificity the last definition is used.

Example:

```
@media (max-width:1300px) {
  p { color:green; }
}
@media (min-width:1000px) {
  p { color:red; }
}
```

For a browser between 1000 and 1300 pixels both rulesets apply, and since both contained rules are equally specific the latter 'wins' - paragraphs will be red.

More on how CSS cascades [can be found here in the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade), specifically section 6.4.3 is a must-read for every webdeveloper.